# sed / awk convert all PHP header() statements to JS window.location

Tags: php, regex, awk, sed

We know that in PHP, we must *never* [Call header() after output is sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46263364/call-header-after-output-is-sent), always *before*.

So, if I need to, I can do [Redirect a user after the headers have been sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066527/redirect-a-user-after-the-headers-have-been-sent) with JavaScript `window.location`.

But, from my own oversight, I put `header()` redirects in too much of my logic for `includes/*.php` files, which show up after I start my `<html>` because of `header.php`, et cetera.

tl;dr

Now, I have:

- `includes/` full of .php files
- These are are loaded with `header()` redirects
- I want to change them all to a JavaScript `window.location` redirects

Normally, I'd fix this with `sed`...

## But, it's complicated

- Sometimes I used `"Location: ${curley_brackets}"`.
- Other times I just `"Location: $simple_variable"`.
- I may even use a `CONSTANT` like this `header("Location: " . HOME_URL);`

So, I not only need to make sure to match...

**`"${gohere}?${getargs}"`** :

```php
header("Location: ${gohere}?${getargs}");
```

...becomes-->

```php
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "' . "${gohere}?${getargs}" . '" </script>';
```

**`"$gohere"`** :

```php
header("Location: $gohere");
```

...becomes-->

```php
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "' . "$gohere" . '" </script>';
```

**`HOME_URL`** :

```php
header("Location: " . HOME_URL);
```

...becomes-->

```php
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "' . HOME_URL . '" </script>';
```

Fortunately, I always used `"double quotes"` in my `header( "Location: ..." )` statements.

But, I couldn't with `CONSTANTS` and I'm not sure how `$1` type args work. And, I'm not even sure if it needs `sed` or `awk`.

So, I need:

- Whatever was in `"doubld quotes"` to end up in `"doubld quotes"`
- Whatever was outside `"doubld quotes"` to end up outside `"doubld quotes"`, ie `CONSTANTS`
- And, I'm not certain what the `${gohere}?${getargs}` or or `HOME_URL` variables may be, I need regex and args
- It must match only `header()` statements at the start of the line and no other content of the PHP code.
- It has many files, so it needs to work on `$PWD/*.php`

...using `sed` or `awk` or some other magic Linux has OOB.

[Redirect a user after the headers have been sent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7066527/redirect-a-user-after-the-headers-have-been-sent)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ cat input_file
header("Location: ${gohere}?${getargs}");
header("Location: $gohere");
header("Location: " . HOME_URL);
```

```
$ sed -E 's|[^ ]* (.*)(")\);\|.* (.*)\);|echo '"'"'<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "'"'"' . \2\1\2\3 . '"'"'" </script>'"'"';|' input_file
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "' . "${gohere}?${getargs}" . '" </script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "' . "$gohere" . '" </script>';
echo '<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "' . HOME_URL . '" </script>';
```

Comment: I ran this: `sed 's|[^ ]* (.*)(")\);\|.* (.*)\);|echo '"'"'<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "'"'"' . \2\1\2\3 . '"'"'" </script>'"'"';|' *.php | grep 'window.location'` Then got this error: `sed: -e expression #1, char 118: Unmatched ) or \)`

Comment: @JesseSteeleיִשַׁי That is because you removed the `-E` flag. Please add it to have extended capabilities

Comment: This: `sed 's|[^ ]* (.*)(")\);\|.* (.*)\);|echo '"'"'<script type="text/javascript"> window.location = "'"'"' . \2\1\2\3 . '"'"'" </script>'"'"';|' *.php | grep 'window.location'` doesn't change what I need, but it does change a lot of other stuff. I need it to work against ./*.php. If it is ready to do that, could you please explain how the `cat input_file` statement helps?

Comment: Sorry, my comment was misleading. I did before, and ran your exact script again. I'm still getting a lot of other stuff caught in the filters, including `$q` statements for queries, ternary statements, and function definitions. It's getting a log of other stuff than just the `header()` statements.

Comment: @JesseSteeleיִשַׁי As the question was answered based on the samples provided and give the expected output for the conditions presented, I'd advise asking another question with the specifics that need to be further addressesd. Bear in mind a question should address a single issue and not multiple if possible.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244958/discussion-between-jesse-steele--and-hatless).

Comment: Discussion is in the chat, but to date, while this is useful, it has yet to be a viable solution. It needs to match against other text, this matches arbitrarily. It doesn't even search for a pattern containing "`header`".

Comment: @JesseSteeleיִשַׁי I responded with an updated answer in the discussion hours ago. It is hard to know whether your most recent comment is in regards to the response there or the last response here.